# Why doesn't my home cool down when the air conditioners run?

Tags: hvac, central-air

I have two HVAC systems (2x condenser outside, 2x evap in).  I just got them repaired after they started leaking two years ago (have not used it for two years). Both AC's came with the house, and I remember them working better than they did before the leak and repair.

1ST AC, DOWN STAIRS, 14 SEER SYS: 
High ceiling. When I turn it on I know it works - with limitations. For some reason, there is no temp change. If its 80 degrees outside, it will be 80 degrees inside. The only thing I can verify that's happening is that it is removing humidity from the air (water being removed from the evap system to outside house via pipe)There is a difference in temp between what the room is and what vent is -approx 13 degrees, but the air flow from the vent is really low.

2nd AC, Upstairs- all bedrooms:
Same issue as above, but the return air is in the main part of the house. So, at night, if I turn on just the bedrooms and leave off the main part of the house, I continually get air from a hot house.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check to see that the motor speed on the air handler on the downstairs unit is set right. These usually are connected so that the blower speed is high for the a/c and lower for heating. If you turn the thermostat to fan only is the air flow higher?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. It seems significant that two separate systems are misbehaving; I wonder what might be common between them.

Answer (score 0):

I would check the temperature drop across the cooling coil. In the "good old days" a 15 to 20 degree drop was the norm. The 13 degree drop you are reading is low but it needs to be taken at the cooling coil and not at the supply and return air registers. There may still be a problem with the outdoor units not having the correct refrigerant charge or other problem. If the A/C units are sized correctly you should be able to cool the house down to a comfortable temperature.

Comment: Maybe more heat gain than unit capacity.